# Vlookup without a range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Looking for Vlookup till the last row. Is there a way to do without giving a range? Can it do till the last row.

```
    Do While IsEmpty(Cells(i, Name)) = False
        Str = Cells(i, Name)

        ws2.Select

        On Error Resume Next
        Corp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Str, ws2.Range("G2:S3000"), 4, False)
        result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Str, ws2.Range("G2:S3000"), 13, False)
        'Band = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Str, ws2.Range("G2:S2500"), 7, False)

        If (Err <> 0) Then
        Else
            ws1.Select
            If (result <> 0) Then
                Cells(i, 10) = result
            End If
            Cells(i, 9) = Corp
        End If

        i = i + 1
        ws1.Select
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one cell that is in the range you want to use (Like G2 in your example) You could use Range("G2").CurrentRegion. This will give you the complete range that the cell belongs to.
This works for me:

```
Public Sub GetLookupValue()  
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim str As String
  str = "c"
  Set rng = Blad1.Range("G2").CurrentRegion
  Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(str, rng, 2, False)
  Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: On Error Resume Next
        Corp = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Str, ws2.Range("G2"), 4, False)
        result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Str, ws2.Range("G2"), 13, False)

Comment: Would like to get an answer. Is there a way to look till end of the row in this code